# How to make changes to the C: directory via ClickOnce deployment?

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, clickonce

I intend to add files in  the C: of a client machine that checks for updates  via ClickOnce
Deployment ..  If it is possible , I would like to know how to do it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, because the C:\ root folder in Windows does not grant write permissions to standard users by default (it's been this way since Windows 2000) and a big purpose of ClickOnce is for IT departments to allow end users to install and update clickonce apps without having to grant them additional security permissions on their local machines.

Anyway, keeping files in this location is a really poor practice. There's no good reason to need to do this; much better to put this kind of thing in places like the user's App Data folder or the default/public documents folder.